# Is there a way to set up a location reminder with an alarm sound on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders, geolocation

I set up a location reminder in my iPhone which reminds me to check something when I get home, however I can't seem to figure out how to get it to sound an alarm, all that it does is flash a reminder on my iPhone screen which doesn't really get my attention.

I looked at some geofencing apps, but not sure about them.

Is there a way to set up a location reminder with an alarm sound on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to use the Shortcuts app.

In the Automation tab, add a personal automation and set it to trigger when you arrive at the location, as an action you can use "Start Timer" and set it to x seconds/minutes.